# How to get access to /sdcard/Android/data/<package_name> folder in Android 11

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, adb, android-11

I am trying to run a script where I have to access /data folder. In android 11 it gives Permission denied error.

> adb shell "ls /sdcard/Android/data/<package_name>/files"

ls: /sdcard/Android/data/<package_name>/files: Permission denied

Can anyone please help me how to fix this programmatically without rooting device.

Comment: It should not be possible to fix this programmatically without rooting the device. App-specific external storage is now private to the app.

Comment: Yes, and is crazy because the Files app can access these files if you activate "Show all Play folders" and then navigate to Play files -> Android -> data -> (package name) -> files